# T-SQL query becomes very slow after large number of rows are deleted

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing

If I insert and then delete a large number of rows from a table, queries running on the table become very slow. The table does not have a index but creating one solves the problem. But what I do not understand is why did the performance degrade in the first place. I have also tried to update the statistics on the table after the delete but that does not improve the performance. Any thoughts?

Here is the setup:

```
use tempdb;
go

drop table if exists dbo.MAvg;
CREATE TABLE dbo.MAvg
(id  INT   NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) ,
 val FLOAT NULL);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.MAvg(val) VALUES
(1), (2), (3), (4), (1), (2), (3), (4), (1), (2);
GO

--A sample query which calculates moving average using a loop. I can do it using recursive CTE and cursor as well both of which will also show performance degradation
--It takes a few milliseconds to execute the query
declare @EMA_results as table(id int, val float, EMA float)
insert into @EMA_results
select top (1) id, val, val as EMA
from MAvg 
order by id asc

while @@ROWCOUNT>0
begin
insert into @EMA_results(id, val, EMA)
    select nxt.id, nxt.val, round((.7*nxt.val + .3*prev.EMA),2) as EMA 
    from MAvg as nxt inner join @EMA_results as prev
    on prev.id + 1 = nxt.id and prev.id = (select max(id) from @EMA_results)
end

select * 
from @EMA_results

--Now insert 1000000 rows. 
delete from MAvg;
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('MAvg', RESEED, 0);
;with cte(n) as
(
select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 union select 10
)
insert into MAvg(val)
    select ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%6)+1
        from cte as num1
        cross join cte as num2
        cross join cte as num3
        cross join cte as num4
        cross join cte as num5
        cross join cte as num6;

--now delete these rows and insert the 10 original rows
delete from MAvg;
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('MAvg', RESEED, 0);
INSERT INTO dbo.MAvg(val) VALUES
(1), (2), (3), (4), (1), (2), (3), (4), (1), (2);

--After deleting large number of rows, the same query takes 13 seconds to execute
declare @EMA_results as table(id int, val float, EMA float)
insert into @EMA_results
select top (1) id, val, val as EMA
from MAvg 
order by id asc

while @@ROWCOUNT>0
begin
insert into @EMA_results(id, val, EMA)
    select nxt.id, nxt.val, round((.7*nxt.val + .3*prev.EMA),2) as EMA 
    from MAvg as nxt inner join @EMA_results as prev
    on prev.id + 1 = nxt.id and prev.id = (select max(id) from @EMA_results)
end

select * 
from @EMA_results
```

Comment: I am not trying to avoid creating an index. What I am trying is to understand the 'why' behind this behaviour.

Comment: Not quite - a table without a *clustered* index is a heap; a table with only non-clustered indexes is also a heap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is due to the logical reads performed on `MAvg`.

Initially, the IO statistics for the table are

```
Scan Count  Logical Reads   
        31  86

sp_spaceused shows rows 10, reserved 72KB
```

`select * from MAvg` shows logical reads=1

After deleting the rows and re-inserting, the statistics shows

```
Scan Count  Logical Reads   
        31  145,518

sp_spaceused shows rows 10, reserved 192KB
```

`select * from MAvg` now shows logical reads=16

This is likely because just deleting rows does nothing to deallocate the `pages` the table now occupies and the table is a `heap`.

If you `truncate` instead of deleting the issue does not exist.

If you create a unique clustered index

```
create unique clustered index Idx_Id on mavg(id) with(fillfactor=100)
```

the issue also doesn't exist because the re-inserted rows all exist on a single page.

Comment: Yes, the pages in the heap are not being 'garbage collected'. The 'Total pages' and 'Total used pages' count for before and after deletion is respectively 2608 and 2606. I would have assumed the 'Total used pages' count would go down. But not. Strange!

Comment: As mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#locking-behavior, in addition to truncate, I could also use DELETE with TABLOCK hint to deallocate the pages

Comment: That's also useful to know.

Comment: @umbersar Quite common with heaps to have ghost rows. One of the reasons you should always have a clustered index